# PostgreSQL - Foreign Key References Mutually Exclusive Tables

Tags: postgresql

I have three database tables: ALIENS, MONSTERS, and TROPHIES.

Each ALIEN can have multiple TROPHIES.
Each MONSTER can have multiple TROPHIES.
Each TROPHY must have exactly one WINNER (ALIEN XOR MONSTER).

Is there a way to have a foreign key in the TROPHY table that references the primary key of either an ALIEN or a MONSTER?

Or is it easier to simply have two tables: an ALIEN_TROPHY table and a MONSTER_TROPHY table (even though they would be identical)?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot create a PLAYERS table that contains both ALIENS and MONSTERS plus a flag indicating player type?

Comment: It's because the logic for ALIENS and MONSTERS (in a server side app) is vastly different, and they have different fields.

Answer (score 2):

You could create two foreign keys with a check constraint that says exactly one is empty:

```
create table alien (id int primary key);
create table monster (id int primary key);
create table trophy (id int primary key,
    alien_id int references alien(id),
    monster_id int references monster(id),
    check (alien_id is null <> monster_id is null)
);
```

Comment: This is what I have been doing for now, but I was wondering if there was a way to have a single field reference two different tables.